# How to compare string in JSTL c:if

Tags: jsp, if-statement, jstl

```
 <c:set var="name" value="${param.byName}"></c:set>
 <c:out value="${name}"></c:out>  // Here the value is displaying

 <c:forEach var="viewlist1" items="${inwardList}">
   <c:if test="${name eq viewlist1.vendor} ">
    <c:out value="${viewlist1.vendor}"></c:out>  // Here I am not getting
   </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

JSTL c:if is not comparing with String variables, can anyone help me in this.

Comment: If "you're not getting", it simply means that the name is not equal to viewlist1.vendor according to String.equals(). Case matters, white space matters. It could also mean that there is no element at all in inwardList.

Comment: inwardList is a list of object , if I print before if as `<c:out value="${viewlist1.vendor}"></c:out> ` it prints all values. Here I am just filtering for perticular type of name.

Comment: Add debugging statements. Print the length and the value of each string for example.